# In-Place Quicksort w/ Last Element Pivot?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement In-Place Quicksort, with the last element as my pivot. Attached below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] input = {3,2,4,6,10,1,9,7,5};
        quickSort(input, 0, input.length-1);
    }
    public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    }

    public static int partition(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        int pivot = arr[right];
        int high = right-1;

        while(left < high){
            while(arr[left] < pivot){
                left++;
            }
            while(arr[high] > pivot){
                high--;
            }
            swap(arr,left, high);
            left++;
            high--;
        }
        swap(arr, left, pivot);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        return left;
    }

    public static void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        int index = partition(arr, left, right);
        quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
        quickSort(arr, index, right);
    }
```

For some reason, my code is giving me an IndexOutOfBounds Exception, and it does not accurately sort the array. I am not sure why I am getting this error.

If I understand correctly, we should make the last element our pivot. Then, we iterate the left pointer right, until we find an element greater than the pivot. After that, we do the same from the right side (keep moving left), until we find an element smaller than the pivot. Then we swap these elements and continue doing the same thing.

Finally, when the left/right pointer are the same, we swap the center value with our pivot.

Is this the correct way of thinking about it? And if so, what errors does my code have? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: An IndexOutOfBoundsException is pretty self-explanatory; you're using an index that is too large or small (negative) for the array in question. Also, asking for the community to find all errors in your code is off-topic.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It is what this site is _for_. But OP should do more work, like post the exact stack trace and try to debug this by printing out the interim results.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, exactly. So, when you ask "what errors does my code have" it's off-topic. That's requesting a debugging service which this site *isn't*.

Comment: Going forward, I would strongly advise that you post the specific test cases you're running and the specific bounds error you're getting. That information allows us to reproduce the error more easily, and the specific bounds error you're getting can often serve as a guide for debugging (you'd treat a negative index access differently than a large positive index access.)

Answer (score 4):

A few errors:

- Add `left < high` checks to your inner loops. You should check it every time you modify left or right.
- Check `arr[high] >= pivot` not `arr[high] > pivot`.
- `swap(arr, left, pivot);` is wrong. You should swap left with pivot using positions, not values. It should be `swap(arr, left, right);`.
- You should check `left < right` in your quicksort method.

When you fix these errors, your code should look like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] input = {3,2,4,6,10,1,9,7,5};
        quickSort(input, 0, input.length-1);
    }
    public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
        int tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    }

    public static int partition(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        int pivot = arr[right];
        int high = right;

        while(left < high){
            while(left < high && arr[left] < pivot){
                left++;
            }
            while(left < high && arr[high] >= pivot){
                high--;
            }
            swap(arr,left, high);
        }
        swap(arr, left, right);
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(arr));
        return left;
    }

    public static void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        if( left < right)
        {
            int index = partition(arr, left, right);
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Finally found the solution which I was looking, I must say with this approach.
Thanks for saving hours.

Answer (score 0):

Trace through this code on the assumption that the final array element is the smallest element. The loop to adjust high will continuously decrement high because each other array element is bigger than the pivot, so eventually high will drop off the front of the array, leading to your out of bounds access.

To fix this, add in another check in that loop to ensure you haven't had high and left cross. You may then need to add in some extra logic afterwards to handle that as a special case.

Comment: The extra check will decrease performance, especially for nearly sorted input (where mispredicted branches don't dominate), but it doesn't seem avoidable with that choice of pivot. Choosing a pivot from the middle is normally preferred because we have a guarantee that the `>` and `<` checks will fail at some point through the array.